# Catch apollo client errors when using errorLink

Tags: error-handling, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using [Apollo error link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-error/) to handle graphQL errors.
In most cases, I would only want to catch the error and show an alert, which is something I can easily to when defining `onError`, but in one of my views I'm running a mutation call and there I would like to catch the error as well so that I can do cleanup actions if the call fails. To demonstrate:

ErrorLink:

```js
export const processError = (error_message: string, operation_name: string, variables: any) => {
  alert(error_message)
};

export const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, response, operation }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, path }) => {
      processError(message, operation.operationName, operation.variables);
    });
  } else {
    ...
  }
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: errorLink.concat(httpLink),
});
```

The View's call

```js
const [GQL_createDineInOrder, { error, data }] = useMutation(createDineInOrder);
  console.log({ error, data });

...
// At some point I call the function:
try {
  const response = await GQL_createDineInOrder({ variables });
  console.log({ response });
} catch(error) {
  // Here I would like to run some clean up actions with functions defined in the View.
  console.log({ error })
}
```

when ran, console log prints `error` and `data` as undefined and the second and third console logs never run. It is expected since errorLink catches the error before these execute.

There are two bad options I have:

1. Do not throw an error on the graphQL call but returns success with `error` in the response <- I would rather handle errors on GraphQL as errors and not pass them camouflaged as a successful response.
2. Import all the cleanup functions from the View to errorLink, check for the `path` and if it's the correct call, run them from there. <- this is obviously terrible.

Is there something I can do to be able to catch the error in the View as well or instead of errorLink for this call?